# How to get the text from a text Box in UI when the text is not present in DOM?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby

I have a text box in the UI from which I want to get the text. The problem is the text is not present in the dom. It is inserted through some javascript/jquery. How to get the text from the text box in such case?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the placeholder or the value attribute. Could you share some more insight.

Comment: Please add the relevant screenshot of how it looks like in UI.

Comment: I am talking about the value attribute.

Comment: Does a value attribute exist once there is text in the field?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to access is the `value` property (current contents of the field) - which is different than the `value` attribute - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html.  selenium-webdriver used to only provide an `attribute` method on `::Selenium::WebDriver::Element` objects which would return the property if a string property value existed, and otherwise would return the attribute value.  Newer versions of selenium-webdriver now also provide a `property` method on the objects which will return just the property.  Assuming you have found the relevant `element` by some method (id, css, xpath, etc) then in recent versions of selenium-webdriver you should be able to do

```
element.property('value')
```

In older versions of selenium-webdriver you would do

```
element.attribute('value')
```